# C++ templated metaprogramming, checking if a struct has a field

Tags: c++, templates, macros, template-meta-programming

So I recently discovered C++ does have reflections, it just happens no one, not even the C++ committee knew it yet until a Russian genius opened the door to an impossible to debug world of possibilities.

With that preface, let's look at this crime against humanity:

```
template <typename T, typename D = decltype(T().field)>
struct foo { bool b = true; };

template <typename T>
struct foo<T, void> { bool b = false; };

template <typename T>
constexpr bool HasField() { return foo<T>().b; }
```

That compiles and it works. Given any type whose members are not private, you can check whether or not the type defines a filed named `field`.

However, this forces you to write that pattern for every field you want to check for. It will work, but it will add a bunch of copy pasta everywhere and uglify the code (not that the code will be pretty if you copy that even once into it).

So, for sheer curiosity, I am trying to think what's the least disgusting way to make a generic POD field check.

One idea I had was this:

```
#define HAS_FIELD(field) \
    template <typename T, typename D = decltype(T().#field)> \
    struct foo_#field { bool b = true; }; \
    \
    template <typename T> \
    struct foo_#field<T, void> { bool b = false; }; \
    \
    template <typename T> \
    constexpr bool HasField#field() { return foo<T>().b; }
```

This at least reduces the number of lines one has to write to just one macro invocation. But I am not satisfied, I am trying to see if we can use templates and macros to get a function that can be called anywhere without needing to preface stuff with macros.

i.e. We want to get to be able to do (or similar):

```
struct POD {/**/};
int main() { HasField(POD, FieldName); }
```

Note that currently it's almost possible:

```
struct POD {/**/};
HAS_FIELD(FieldName)
int main() { HasFieldFieldName<POD>(); }
```

Again the point isn;t whether this is a good idea, it's whether we can.

Comment: You want to read about [concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints). And this is not reflection.

Comment: How do you define reflection? It's meta analyzing the fields of a structure,  aka inspection, which is one of the features of reflection. And this is not the only thing you can do with this form of meta programming, you can count all the fields in the structure, cast structures to tuples generically, get the sizes of each field... But I digress.

Also I am not sure how concepts help here, the point is, the above code gives you a boolean you can use at runtime to do logic with. Like calling a function if the field exists.

Comment: @Makogan A key part of the definition of reflection is that it happens at runtime. There is no such thing as compile-time reflection. What we have here is compile-time introspection, not reflection.

Comment: See requires-expression.

Comment: @cdhowie that seems like an arbitrary requirement, and if that;s teh case, take up the battle with the organizers of cpp con:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abdeAew3gmQ

Comment: @Makogan Terms have definitions. You can call them arbitrary but that doesn't change what they are. I could pick any other computer science term and label part of its definition as "arbitrary." That doesn't mean I should start using it incorrectly. When talking with others who know the definition, I will either confuse them or look ignorant.

Comment: Yeah yeah, and we can have a pedantic discussion on the official term. Whenever I have seen the term used it refers to meta inspection of the variables, the source I got these techniques from calls it reflection and even mathematical terms are context sensitive, after all the defintion of ring will change depending  on the textbook you read. I am not particularily interested in trying to convince you whether the use of the term is correct here or not, it's consistent with the source so i am sticking to that.

Comment: This is not reflection because it doesn't let you do what reflection does in languages that support reflection natively. It lets you do a very, very, very small part of it. It is a pale shadow of a reflection (pardon the pun).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might wrap in a functor (as lambda):

```
// C++20
#define HasField(C, Field) \
    [](){ \
        return overloaded{[]<typename T>(int) -> decltype(std::declval<T>().Field, void(), std::true_type()) { return {}; }, \
                          []<typename T>(...) { return std::false_type{}; }}.operator()<C>(0); \
    }()
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/858b11954db936ee)

Comment: What would the definition of overloaded be?

Comment: I provided links with that (taken from [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit)'s example).

Answer (score 1):

There is a generic technique presented in the book "C++ template, the complete guide" (thus this is not from me!), to test for member variable/function, class nested type. Here is an example:

```
namespace details
{
template <typename F, typename... Args, typename = decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<Args &&>()...))>
auto
IsValidImpl(void *) -> std::true_type;

template <typename F, typename... Args>
auto
IsValidImpl(...) -> std::false_type;
} // namespace details

inline constexpr auto gk_isValid = [](auto f) {
  using InputType = decltype(f);
  return [](auto &&... args) { return decltype(details::IsValidImpl<InputType, decltype(args) &&...>(nullptr)){}; };
};

template <typename T>
struct TypeT
{
  using Type = T;
};

template <typename T>
constexpr auto gk_type = TypeT<T>{};

template <typename T>
T ValueT(TypeT<T>);

struct Foo {
    int bar;
};

struct Bar {
};

inline constexpr auto HasBar = gk_isValid([](auto x) -> decltype((void)ValueT(x).bar) {});

static_assert(HasBar(gk_type<Foo>), "foo has bar");
static_assert(!HasBar(gk_type<Bar>), "bar has no bar");
```

Example for checking nested type or operator:

```
constexpr auto hasSizeType = isValid([](auto x) -> typename decltype((void)valueT(x))::size_type {});
constexpr auto hasLess = isValid([](auto x, auto y) -> decltype(valueT(x) < valueT(y)) {});
```

Of course, you will need a kind of macro wrapping to make it more usable. But it is a first step to genericity...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [BOOST_MPL_HAS_XXX_TRAIT_DEF](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/has-xxx-trait-def.html).

For example:

```
BOOST_MPL_HAS_XXX_TRAIT_DEF(Juju)
```

defines `has_Juju<T>` type with `::value` equal `true` or `false`

Then one may use it like this:

```
#include <boost/mpl/has_xxx.hpp>

BOOST_MPL_HAS_XXX_TRAIT_DEF(Juju)
template <class T>
bool isThereAnyJuju()
{
   return boost::mpl::bool_<has_Juju<T>::value>();
}
```

Templates may also use knowledge of having or not having field with that name by using nice [boost::mpl::bool_](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/bool.html)

```
#include <boost/mpl/bool_fwd.hpp>
... boost::mpl::bool_<has_Juju<T>::value> ...
```

Answer (score 0):

[Run this code](https://godbolt.org/z/f4YqY4j48)

```
#define HasField(C, F)                               \
    []() {                                           \
        auto check = [](auto u) -> decltype(u.F) {}; \
        return std::invocable<decltype(check), C>;   \
    }();
```